# Core Data Attribute Type Differences

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I'm having a difficult time understanding the size differences of the data types.

I have an attribute called `displayOrder` with type of `Integer 16`. I use this attribute to maintain a display order of tableViewCells, added by a user in a tableView. I set the value with plain numbers, "1, 2, 3", and it's working fine.

But there's also a lot of other options like `Integer 32`, `Integer 64`, `Decimal`, `Float`, and `Double`. I did my own research and found that a Float can have a decimal point, and a Double is double the size of the Float (Not sure the difference between Decimal and Float).

My question is, if the differences of these are just the size, does that mean I have to worry about displayOrder going up to, for example "1000", and it will exceed the bits of `Integer 16` (Does it ever exceed the size?), and therefore I should use `Integer 32` instead? And if I set it to `Integer 64`, and if the displayOrder is just "1", do I have to worry about slow performance?

I've seen the docs [NSAttributeType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSAttributeType) but not sure what the numbers stands for.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @choppin meant that speed wise it won't make much of a difference. Size wise it very much does, an int16 is half the size of int32, and having a ton of int32s when you only need int16s will have a larger memory footprint. The number here represents the number of bits the variable takes up in memory.

If you will only have a couple then don't worry about it, but if you will have a large data set, then it becomes an issue.

Also, if the number you will store can possibly be a very large number then you need the bigger option, for example an int32 can store 4,294,967,296 or half this if the Int is signed which it is by default. If you go over the maximum size of a signed int then the number wraps around, going negative or to 0 for a signed int.

Since memory is a concern on a mobile device then which option you choose warrants thought, though it warrants less that it did a few years ago.

Comment: What happens if signed int goes negative or 0, or if unsigned int exceeds the number? Does the attribute become null?

Comment: They wrap around. A unsigned int is positive, and it will go to either 0 or the largest number depending on what value it is and which way it moves, adding or subtracting. Signed ints will go from maximum positive to maximum negative, or vice versa, depending on its value and if you add or subtract. If you look at it like a loop it's easy to understand. The maximum and minimum values are connected to each other. Add 1 to the max and you get the min. You can go either way on this loop.

Comment: I probably should look into more about signed ints and unsigned ints. Sorry, I'm still not fully understanding this. If I understood you right, if I use Int16 it will use less memory. But if the numbers wrap around, does that mean it will not cause any problem when data stored is larger than Int16?? Then what's the point of using larger type Int32 and Int64? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: This is definitely a subject that anyone serious about programming should know and I highly recommend understanding this because it will help you from getting strange results dealing with large numbers. The problems using the smaller type with too large a number is that you will get logic errors and not crashes.

Comment: That makes more sense, that "you will get logic errors and not crashes". I probably shouldn't worry about those since mine is only a display order. I understand bit more now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't make a huge deal on performance which one you use, but I would stick with integer 32.  That gives you 2 to the power of 32 values (which should be more than enough for a display order)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still,  I don't understand why Apple added the option to choose between different sizes, if it makes no difference. I tend to spend too much time on these small things :(